# Unable to open Seagate HDD in MacBook Air running on macOS Mojave 10.14 (Using Paragon NTFS for Mac)

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, external-disk, mount, hdd

Please advise on how to open the HDD again. This previously worked fine and also HDD works on Windows 10. I am using Paragon NTFS for Mac to read the HDD.

[image]

Comment: Hi Arjun! You should open paragon(if active) OR format the drive(cleans everything ) to macOS compatible format. Currently it is NTFS which is the file system of windows which is read-only for Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WD MyBook appears as read-only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140724/wd-mybook-appears-as-read-only)